# Controller pagination with a subquery

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I want to use this MySQL query in my controller without using query().

```
SELECT * FROM T1 INNER JOIN
(SELECT T1.id
FROM T1 
INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.T1_id
INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.T3_id = T3.id
WHERE 
1 = 1
GROUP BY T1.id
HAVING COUNT(*) = 1) AS T1_x ON T1.id = T1_x.id
```

Can't figure out waht the code in my controller would be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one way how you can join a subquery in CakePHP

My models name here is T1

```
    $this->paginate = array(
    'paramType' => 'querystring',
    'joins' => array(
        array(
        'table' => '(SELECT T1.id
                    FROM T1 
                    INNER JOIN T2 ON T1.id = T2.T1_id
                    INNER JOIN T3 ON T2.T3_id = T3.id
                    WHERE 
                    1 = 1
                    GROUP BY T1.id
                    HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)'
            'alias' => 'T1_x',
            'type' => 'INNER',
            'conditions' => array('T1_x.id = T1.id')
            )
        )
);


$T1 = $this->paginate();
```